# Adding a background image to a JPanel

Tags: java, image, swing, jpanel, paintcomponent

I'm working on building a board game in Java.  For the game board itself I was trying to place the image of the board as the background of the entire JPanel, which fills the JFrame.  I found a way to do this, but only with the file stored locally, it needs to be able to take the image from the package the GUI is inside as well.

```
package Gui;

import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import javax.imageio.ImageIO;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

//Proof of concept for setting an image as background of JPanel

public class JBackgroundPanel extends JPanel {
    private BufferedImage img;

    public JBackgroundPanel() {
        // load the background image
        try {
            img = ImageIO.read(new File(
                    "C:\\Users\\Matthew\\Desktop\\5x5     Grid.jpg"));
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        super.paintComponent(g);
        // paint the background image and scale it to fill the entire space
        g.drawImage(img, 0, 0, getWidth(), getHeight(), this);
    }
}
```

I've read that using ImageIcon is a good fix, but I don't know how to use it properly.

Edit 1 - I found my answer here 
http://www.coderanch.com/how-to/java/BackgroundImageOnJPanel 
I also had the picture formatted wrong in my workspace.  Thanks for the help

Comment: You'll want to search this site as this has been asked a lot. if you're looking to access an image from a jar file, then you'll want to do it as a resource, i.e., `ImageIO.read(getClass().getResourceAsStream(resourcePath));` The resources path will be relative to your class files.

Comment: Note: ImageIcon is *not* a "good fix".

Answer (score 6, accepted):

1. Make sure the resource you want to load is located within the Jar file
2. Use `getClass().getResource("/path/to/resource")` to obtain a `URL` reference to the resource, which can be used by `ImageIO` to read the resource

So, for example, if the image was located in the /images folder inside your Jar, you could use

```
 ImageIO.read(getClass().getResource("/images/5x5    Grid.jpg"));
```

For example...

Comment: Yep, exactly, 1+. Something about the spaces in the file name makes me itch though.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels Yeah, the spaces make me skittish as well

Comment: The spaces were a bad copy, the file name is 5x5 Grid.gif, 1 single space.

Comment: So now that I've used your example                                      img = ImageIO.read(getClass().getResource("/images/5x5 Grid.jpg")); img becomes a URL type, and the paintComponet portion cannot take a URL as an argument

Comment: No, `ImageIO` takes a `URL` (amongst other things), reads in the image a returns a `BufferedImage`.  You paint the `BufferedImage`